# Microsoft Publisher Mail Merge - Formatting currency fields

Tags: formatting, mail-merge, microsoft-publisher

After adding merge record field, I'm not getting an option to Format for certain fields. I have about 10 fields to publisher document and two of these fields cannot be formatted (Format icon is grayed out). I have removed and reentered the fields, but still no option to format them to currency.